# Generic memoize utility function for pure functions

Tags: php, functional-programming, memoization

Given the following generic memoize utility for pure functions with type hints:

```php
function memoize(callable $fn, callable $serialize = null): callable {
    $serialize = $serialize ? $serialize : 'serialize';

    return function(...$args) use ($fn, $serialize) {
        static $cache = [];
        $k = $serialize($args);
        return isset($cache[$k]) ? $cache[$k] : ($cache[$k] = $fn(...$args));
    };
}
```

Is the **callable** type hint here preferred as opposed to **closure**? I'm also not sure if I'm being too pedantic with the type hints and whether my use of **static** here is recommended?

I'd appreciate any feedback on the code above.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Ngoy I've not seen this before, but had a quick look at how it is supposed to be used (https://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-and-using-memoization-in-php/).  Can you should me a [mvce] of how you are calling this function with sample data?

Comment: @Mast sorry about that, I'll be sure to do a careful read of that post for questions going forward. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @mickmackusa Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ngoylufo/3c1e9257dfeec3c152dba1d1e1de2fdb). It's a simplified version of a use case that I have. The main idea of the function is to allow one to pass a custom serialization function for the given arguments as some built in classes are not serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address your first question:

> Is the callable type hint here preferred as opposed to closure?

There is a very similar question on StackOverflow: [*PHP: Type hinting - Difference between `Closure` and `Callable`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29730720/1575353). It has three answers.

The first line of [the answer by Xorifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40942212/1575353) explains:

> The main difference between them is that a [`closure`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) is a *class* and [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) a *type*.

And the last line of [the accepted answer by Rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730810/1575353) has this suggestion:

> So if you only want to type hint anonymous function use: `Closure` and if you want also to allow normal functions use `callable` as type hint.

---

*And now, for <strike>something completely different</strike> general code review comments:*

#### Variable naming

The name `$k` is a little too brief... `$key` isn't very long and describes what the variable is.

#### Simplifying ternary expressions

Correct me if I am mistaken but as long as PHP 5.3+ is used then this line:

> ```
> $serialize = $serialize ? $serialize : 'serialize';
> ```

could be shortened using the fact that:

> The expression `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)` evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to **TRUE**, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to **FALSE**.
>  *Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to **`TRUE`**, and expr3 otherwise.*<sup>[1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)</sup>

to the following:

```
$serialize = $serialize ?: 'serialize';
```

If PHP 7+ is used (which hopefully is the case, since at the time of writing, 7.2+ are actively maintained<sup>[2](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)</sup>) then the [null coalescing operator i.e. `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) could also be used to simplify cases where a fallback should be used if a non-null value does not exist - e.g. :

> ```
>  return isset($cache[$k]) ? $cache[$k] : ($cache[$k] = $fn(...$args));
> ```

Can become:

```
return $cache[$k] ?? ($cache[$k] = $fn(...$args));
```

Comment: Glad to be here, hope I'll get to enjoy it to. Thank you for answering my questions, I'll be sure to check out those answers on StackOverflow. You're right $key would be better and I didn't know about the shortened version of the ternary, that's gonna come in handy.

Comment: The [Elvis Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28443362/2943403) must not be used to check if a variable/element is "declared/set".  For this you must use the null coalescing operator.  Demonstration that the shorthand ternary is not appropriate and may produce Notices because it merely checks for truthiness: https://ideone.com/odUsIq

Comment: @mickmackusa that is a good point and I updated my answer to mention it. The value should be set given the default value. If it was passed a value that wasn’t set then the notice would be thrown for the caller.

Comment: I'd like to see a realistic usage of this memoizing technique so that I can understand what is going on.  It looks like the functionality to is to allow the addition of data to the cache, but not mutate any existing data.  I might yet post a review, but it seems like `$fn` would be better named `$valueMutator` and `$serialize` should be `$keyMutator`.  The Elvis Operator is absolutely fine (though `??` is suitable as well) to use when declaring the fallback for `$serialize`; I was thinking about the `$cache` declaration when promoting the null coalescing operator.